# In Flutter, what is the best widget to dynamically display a list in a dialogue

Tags: flutter, listview, dialog

In my Flutter app I display a list of contact's phone numbers in a dialogue so the user can tap the one they want to use to call or text the contact.
The dialogue will only be shown if the contact has more than 1 number.

I'm using the flutter_dialogs package (may or may not be relevant?)
The problem is I can't figure out how to dynamically set the height of the container.
If I don't specify a height I get errors, I've tried so many things but either the dialogue's height is almost filling the screen or I get errors like RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.., etc.
I've tried wrapping the listview in SingleChildScrollView (with and without physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() and shrinkWrap: true), Column, Row, Align, and goodness knows what else!

height: 100, comfortably displays 2 numbers but if the contact has 3 the 3rd number isn't visible without scrolling and you wouldn't know it's there!

Please help, what widget or setting/property should I use?

The dialog:

```
  showPlatformDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => BasicDialogAlert(
      title: Text("picknumber".tr),
      content: Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          // TODO height shouldn't be fixed
          height: 100, 
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: phoneNumbersList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              String pn = phoneNumbersList[index].value.toString();
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(pn),
                onTap: () {
                  _pickedNumber = pn;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              );
            },
          )
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        BasicDialogAction(
          title: Text("cancel".tr),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            _pickedNumber = null;
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. Try this.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<User> _users = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _users.add(User()
      ..name = "John"
      ..phones = []
      ..phones.add("(875) 225-5490"));

    _users.add(User()
      ..name = "Mike"
      ..phones = []
      ..phones.add("(875) 225-5490")
      ..phones.add("(239) 218-9284")
      ..phones.add("(893) 918-0036")
      ..phones.add("(875) 225-5490"));

    _users.add(User()
      ..name = "Kevin"
      ..phones = []
      ..phones.add("(875) 225-5490")
      ..phones.add("(239) 218-9284")
      ..phones.add("(893) 918-0036")
      ..phones.add("(875) 225-5490"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: _users.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              shadowColor: Colors.black26,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                dense: true,
                onTap: () {
                  if (_users[index].phones.length > 1)
                    ExampleDialog.showyDialog(
                        context: context, user: _users[index]);
                },
                title: Text(_users[index].name),
                subtitle: _users[index].phones.length > 1
                    ? Text("${_users[index].phones.first} Click to see more")
                    : Text(_users[index].phones.first),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  String name;
  List<String> phones;
  User({
    this.name,
    this.phones,
  });
}

class ExampleDialog {
  static Future<void> showyDialog({BuildContext context, User user}) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, right: 3),
          title: Center(
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                  child: Text("View phones"))),
          content: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: user.phones.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Card(
                          shadowColor: Colors.black26,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            dense: true,
                            onTap: () {},
                            title: Text("${user.phones[index]}"),
                          ),
                        );
                      })
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.cancel,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 24.0,
              ),
              label: Text("Close"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you!
I didn't need all of it, I added   
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true, 
to the ListView.builder (again) and wrapped the ListTile in a Card and that did it. Thank  you so much!

Comment: It worked great on Android but now I'm testing on IOS simulator I'm back to square 1!

Comment: unfortunately I do not have IOS and I cannot help you with this problem

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution but it's frustrating that you think something is fixed only to find it's only fixed on one OS!
Thank you for your help in fixing it for Android, I appreciate it and it may help someone else :-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that works for me.
I replaced the listView with a column with mainAxisSize.min, that gets populated with a list of widgets (card(ListTile)).
I tried a ListBody first, which worked fine on iOS simulator but Android emulator gave errors so I used a column.
This method uses the navigator to return the chosen number.

Test code:

```
showPlatformDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => BasicDialogAlert(
      title: Text("Pick a number"),
      content: Column( 
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: getAlertOptions(),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        BasicDialogAction(
          title: Text("Cancel"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
);



List<Widget> getAlertOptions() {
  List<Widget> options = [];
  List<String> lItems = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"];

for (int i = 0; i < lItems.length; i++)

  options.add(
    Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(lItems[i]),
        dense: true,
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          print(lItems[i]);
        },
      ),
    )
  );

  return options;

}
```

App code:

```
Future<String> getPhoneNumber(BuildContext context, List  
    phoneNumbersList) async {
  String _pickedNumber;

if (phoneNumbersList.length == 1) {
  _pickedNumber = phoneNumbersList[0].value;
} else {
  _pickedNumber = await showPlatformDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => BasicDialogAlert(
      title: Text("picknumber".tr),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize:  MainAxisSize.min,
        children: getNumberList(phoneNumbersList),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        BasicDialogAction(
          title: Text("cancel".tr),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            _pickedNumber = null;
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

  return _pickedNumber;

}




List<Widget> getNumberList(List phoneNumbers) {
List<Widget> options = [];

for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++)

options.add(
      Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.blue,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(phoneNumbers[i].value.toString()),
          dense: true,
          onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(phoneNumbers[i].value.toString());
          },
        ),
      )
  );

  return options;
}
```